# Max CPU utilization on heterogeneous Kubernetes cluster with single-core process

Tags: kubernetes, cpu

According to the Kubernetes docs a cluster can have up to 5000 nodes. Imagine I have then node0 with 1CPU, node1 with 2CPU, etc.

Let's say I have a single-core, synchronous process which I want to run instances of. Am I then limited by the smallest node in a heterogeneous cluster of nodes? If not, can I enforce choosing the node largest CPU (which would then limit me to the single node) or smallest CPU (which would then allow seamless and consistent parallel execution) or will Kubernetes do it in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I then limited by the smallest node in a heterogeneous cluster of nodes? If not, can I enforce choosing the node largest CPU (which would then limit me to the single node) or smallest CPU (which would then allow seamless and consistent parallel execution) or will Kubernetes do it in the background?

The scheduler does not have insight about what instances you use. So it will schedule the app to any node.

You can use [Taints and Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/#example-use-cases) to classify the nodes and then you can declare to what kind of nodes you want your app to run on by setting *tolerations*. Or alternatively use [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) and labels on nodes.